# PCA for reducing number of variables

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have 200 variables and about 300 subjects. I wanted to create a subset of variables based on the 200 variables I have. Basically, I wanted to reduce the amount of variables (currently 200) to a smaller number (ex: 10). Can I use factor analysis or PCA?

I tried to do PCA using SPSS but the results seemed weird. The results contained everything (KMO, eigen values, component matrix, etc.). However, there were no results for Bartlett's Test of Sphericity. My first question is, why was the Bartlett's Test of Sphericity not performed?

My 2nd question is: is it OK to do a PCA with 200 variables and 200 subjects?

My third question is: what are other techniques I can use to reduce the number of variables (i.e., dimension reduction)?

Comment: Your first question is specific to SPSS, which I haven't used for decades, but someone should be able to tell you about whether and how to get that test with SPSS, except that that kind of detail is widely considered off-topic here. See advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions.

Comment: Second question: Surely, as with hundreds of variables many people would want to select or calculate fewer to focus on and PCA is often pushed with that as a goal. Third question: That's a large theme in multivariate analysis, and you may get answers here. but better to read around as well. I've added a tag with nearly 1000 questions.